# onResume() makes my application crash with no reason

Tags: java, android, crash, onresume

For some reason when i declare onResume() in my code it crashes my program at the begining for no reason, it doesn't even open up.

This is my onResume() code :

```
public void onResume()
    {
        if(play==true)
        {
            if(playing==false)
            {
                if(numbl>0)
                {
                letter=thefull.substring(cur, cur+1);
                if(letter.equals("m"))
                {
                    oursong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.m);
                    oursong.start();
                    playing=true;
                }
                else if(letter.equals("a"))
                {
                    oursong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a);
                    oursong.start();
                    playing=true;
                }
                else if(letter.equals("r"))
                {
                    oursong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.r);
                    oursong.start();
                    playing=true;
                }
                }
            }


        }

    }
```

as soon as i remove onResume() the program runs just fine.
Am i doing something wrong?

Here is a look of my full code : http://pastebin.com/faVfFK6q

Comment: @user2734723 what are play and playing ?? r they Boolean var?also post ur logcat...and if possible then add line no where error occurs ..!

Comment: play and playing are both boolean.
For some reason my code doesnt work tho, because it doesnt play the sounds like i want after each other.

Answer (score 6):

**you must complete the life cycle of android activity.**

*If you are override onResume() or any method of the life cycle you should call the super.onResume();*

```
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();

/// Your Code
}
```

**UPDATE**

Condition you checking is onResume() method is incorrect.

```
if(play) // UPDATE HERE
        {
            if(!playing)// UPDATE HERE
            {
                if(numbl>0)
                {
                letter=thefull.substring(cur, cur+1);
                if(letter.equals("m"))
                {
                    oursong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.m);
                    oursong.start();
                    playing=true;
                }
                else if(letter.equals("a"))
                {
                    oursong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a);
                    oursong.start();
                    playing=true;
                }
                else if(letter.equals("r"))
                {
                    oursong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.r);
                    oursong.start();
                    playing=true;
                }
                }
            }


        }
```

Comment: It works now.
One more question, i noticed that even tho all my variables are right it doesnt play any sound... do you have an idea why?

Comment: I changed play to play==true to (play) and playing==false to (!false)
But it still doesnt work

Comment: write  if(!playing) instead  if(!false)

Comment: i have changed it but it is still thesame.
here is my new code : http://pastebin.com/jVsckZD8
As you an see it doesnt make sense why it is not playing the sounds

Comment: I appreciate this, my respect